# Updating database model in Flask with functions in views

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new for flask and I am trying to update a model based on different user events in my Flask views. I can access it in shell and can pull up some fields with data stored in it. But I need to update models from views based on certain user events. Following is my model file:

```
class Package(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'package'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    student_id = db.Column(db.Integer, ForeignKey('student_profile.id'))
    stripe_id = db.Column(db.String(45))
    student_email = db.Column(db.String(20))
    subscription_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=today)
    expiry_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=deadline)
    is_active = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=True)
    planname = relationship('Plan', backref=backref('package'))
    package_price = db.Column(db.Integer)
    coupon = db.Column(db.String(12))


    def __init__(self, id, 

        stripe_id, 
        student_email, 
        subscription_date,
        expiry_date,
        is_active, 
        planname, 
        package_price, 
        coupon):
            self.id = id
            self.student_id = student_id
            self.student_email = student_email
            self.subscription_date = subscription_date
            self.expiry_date = expiry_date
            self.is_active = is_active
            self.planname = planname
            self.package_price = package_price
            self.coupon = coupon
```

How to update these in views such as:

```
from models import Package
@app.route('/somelink', methods=['POST'])
def somefunc():
    if studentdidsomething:
         planname = 'somename'
         db.session.commit(planname)


return render_template('sometemplate.html')
```

I need to work directly with database tables so that's why confused because flask has many form flavors. Wtf forms, Alchemyforms and just forms. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your dataset doesn't exist, yet you need to create an instance of your model which represents the dataset, set the properties depending on your user event and add the instance to your session. If you already have an existing dataset you need to query it from your database and update the values you want.

```
from models import Package


@app.route('/somelink/<package_id>', default={'package_id': None}, methods=['POST'])
def somefunc(package_id):
    if package_id is None:
         package = Package()
    else:
         package = Package.query(Package.id=package_id).first_or_404()

    if studentdidsomething:
        package.planname = 'somename'
        db.session.add(package)
        db.session.commit()


    return render_template('sometemplate.html')
```

Here you can call somelink with or without a package_id. If you call without a new package will be created. Otherwise an existing package will be used.

Comment: So I just need one reference to create/change all the model fields details? Also last two sentences are confusing for me of your post. You mean if I call package_id in @app.route then existing package will be created? Just last question that would it determine changes for the current user logged in?

Comment: If you make a post request to url `/somelink/12` you will change the package with id 12. If you make a post request to url `/somelink/` (you don't pass a package id) then a new package will be created.